# Поиск значения в массиве объектов и вывод его порядкового номера с ключом

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

Дан массив объектов. Найти введенное значение в массиве и выести порядковый номер элемента массива с ключом, в котором оно записано. **Пара ключ/значение не уникальны.** 
Выводить инфомацию по всем найденым, либо сообщение про отсутсвие таковых.

Если возможно, посоветуйте, как решить эту задачу, и на что нужно обратить внимание. Буду предельно благоддарен.

Answer (score 0):

Кажется, решил. Отправляю ответ сюда.

```
var array = [
  { a1: 1 },
  { a2: 2 },
  { a3: 3 }, 
  { a4: 4 },
  { a5: 5 }, 
  { a6: 6 },
  { a7: 1 },
  { a8: 3 },
  { a9: 6 },
  { a10: 2 },
  { a11: 4 },
  { a12: 6 }
];

var ahtung = true;
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  for (key in array[i]) {
    if (array[i][key] === 3) {
      console.log("key is:" + key + " index is:" + i);
      ahtung = false;
    }
  }
}

if (ahtung) {
  console.log("Не найдено")
}
```

Comment: Только выводите `i+1` в консоли.

Comment: array[i][key] === 'value' 
 -- прямо через это место выполняю вставку значений

Comment: Я к тому что для второго элемента он выведет значение 1. "Найти введенное значение в массиве и выести порядковый номер " -
1 в данном случае это индекс элемента массива, а не порядковый номер элемента.

Comment: С этим согласен, конечно. :)